# Pure Sass maps and lists

Tags: sass

I've recently started working in a new company, I'm very familiar with Scss but they all work with the older Sass format.

I can't seem to find anywhere online what the equivalent to Scss maps and list are in pure Sass. In Scss I would be able to use something like this and then use the `map-get()` function to retrieve data from the list.

```
$breakpoints : (
    $xl: 1280px,
    $m: 768px,
    $s: 480px
)
```

However this refused to compile in when written in pure Sass format. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of variable `$xl` you should use strings as keys inside maps.

Sass is the same as scss:

```
$breakpoints: (xl: 1280px, m: 768px, s: 480px)

a
  color: red

  @media (sreen only) and (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, xl))
    color: green
```

All that is written at scss will work at sass when you remove braces and semicolons. Something like that.

[Sassmeister demo](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/61dfebac8248b66720422db47abbf370).

Comment: Oh of course my bad, badly copied the source code. The thing I was doing wrong was the indentation, just figured pure sass maps have to be on the same line right